# Flutter web can't be running in localhost

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin

i've running flutter build web
and then copy project web from directory "build/web" into "xmapp/htdocs",
but when open browser its only shown blank white screen and error in console.

this is the screen

[image]

i realized i have to add my local ip into front of link in htdocs/web/flutter_service_worker.js, like this

```
const CORE = [
"/",
"main.dart.js",
"index.html",
"assets/NOTICES",
"assets/AssetManifest.json",
"assets/FontManifest.json"];
```

be like this

```
const CORE = [
"http:192.168.1.9:81/web/",
"http:192.168.1.9:81/web/main.dart.js",
"http:192.168.1.9:81/web/index.html",
"http:192.168.1.9:81/web/assets/NOTICES",
"http:192.168.1.9:81/web/assets/AssetManifest.json",
"http:192.168.1.9:81/web/assets/FontManifest.json"];
```

but nothing happend, whats wrong? please help

Answer (score 0):

Try to add or modify base path to your index.html

```
<base href="/web/">
```